# App compile in android studio but dont run Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to run my android app in my phone it keep giving me this Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'. But when i just sync, it has no problem. Problem comes when i run in my phone (extenal device)

I tried to add these
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
But still the problem is there

dependencies {

```
implementation 'com.github.Yalantis:Context-Menu.Android:1.0.8'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.github.devlight.navigationtabstrip:navigationtabstrip:1.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.6.0'
implementation 'com.github.mancj:SlideUp-Android:2.2.8'
implementation 'ru.ztrap:RxSlideUp2:2.+'
implementation 'net.steamcrafted:materialiconlib:1.1.4'

implementation 'kr.pe.burt.android.lib:fragmentnavigationcontroller:0.0.4'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.Mursaat:AnimatedGradientTextView:v0.0.6'
implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.1'
implementation 'com.tapadoo.android:alerter:2.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.zcweng:switch-button:0.0.3@aar'
implementation 'com.pixplicity.easyprefs:library:1.9.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc2'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc2'
implementation 'io.github.kobakei:ratethisapp:1.2.0'


implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'


implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.0, 3.99.99]'
```

}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath'.
  >   Failed to transform artifact 'butterknife-compiler.jar (com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc2)' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime-jars}.
  >   Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\Dell.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.jakewharton\butterknife-compiler\9.0.0-rc2\dcb492fc3d86c39cdc8d00ccacc259bac7a00634\butterknife-compiler-9.0.0-rc2.jar.
  >   Failed to transform 'C:\Users\Dell.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.jakewharton\butterknife-compiler\9.0.0-rc2\dcb492fc3d86c39cdc8d00ccacc259bac7a00634\butterknife-compiler-9.0.0-rc2.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.v4.content' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 48s
10 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 7 up-to-date